# Can I concatenate strings in Elixir and use the pipe operator?

Tags: elixir, string-concatenation

In Elixir, you can concatenate strings with the `<>` operator, like in `"Hello" <> " " <> "World"`.

You can also use the pipe operator `|>` to chain functions together.

I'm trying to write the Elixir code to format the currency for an online game.

```elixir
def format_price(price) do
  price/10000
  |> Float.round(2)
  |> to_string
  |> <> "g"
end
```

The above results in a syntax error. Am I overlooking a basic function that can concatenate strings? I know I can define one myself, but that seems like creating unnecessary clutter in my code if I can avoid it.

I realize I can accomplish the same thing, by simply chaining the methods together like `to_string(Float.round(price/10000, 2)) <> "g"`, but this syntax isn't as nice to read, and it makes it more difficult to extend the method in the future, if I want to add steps in between.

Does Elixir have ways to concatenate text using the pipe operator, or is that not possible without defining the method yourself?

Comment: FWIW, I find the way you don't like ( nested functions ) more comprehensible than your '|>' version.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, you can, by passing the full path to the function, which in this case is `Kernel.<>`:

```
iex(1)> "foo" |> Kernel.<>("bar")
"foobar"
```

Comment: Thanks - it really threw me off that there's no `String.concat` method in the same way that there's an `Enum.concat` method. I didn't realize that you could call the Kernel methods by just including the full path to the function.

Answer (score 14):

### My two cents

> I realize I can accomplish the same thing, by simply chaining the methods together like to_string(Float.round(price/10000, 2)) <> "g", but this syntax isn't as nice to read, and it makes it more difficult to extend the method in the future, if I want to add steps in between.

You could use **interpolation** instead of **concatenation**. For example, you could do it like this and it's still okay to read, and simple, so easy to modify:

```elixir
def format_price(price) do
  price = (price / 10000) |> Float.round(2)
  "#{price}g"
end
```

### Answering your question

To answer your question:

> Does Elixir have ways to concatenate text using the pipe operator, or is that not possible without defining the method yourself?

As mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559831/2066155) by @Dogbert, you can use `Kernel.<>/2`

Another solution is to use `then/2`.

```elixir
def format_price(price) do
  (price / 10000)
  |> Float.round(2)
  |> to_string()
  |> then(&"#{&1}g")
end
```

or

```elixir
def format_price(price) do
  (price / 10000)
  |> Float.round(2)
  |> to_string()
  |> then(&(&1 <> "g"))
end
```